# syntax error unexpected 'use' (t_use) in php twilio SMS, CALLING etc

Tags: php, twilio

I get an error when I try to use TWILIO. the error is **syntax error unexpected 'use' (t_use) in php** twilio.

Comment: It's the same person that asked the question that answered to help others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the placement of the use statement.

```
//This needs to be at the top of your PHP file, not nested in a conditional eg [IF statements or while loops]: top of your PHP file like as though you are connecting to database.
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
```